# Xcode crashes when there is conflict in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, git, crash, storyboard

I committed my changes to `git` and then asked my teammate to pull from the repository. When he did a pull, it showed a conflict with storyboard. If he clicks on the storyboard file in order to resolve it, Xcode crashes.

Are we doing something wrong here or is Xcode just really buggy?

Answer (score 0):

Well, XCode 4 is really buggy, but if there was a git conflict then the file may be in a weird state related to the conflict/merge. Try to resolve that first then reload the storyboard and see what happens.

Comment: Are are you suggesting using something like `git mergetool` to resolve the conflicts ?

Comment: You could give that a try, yes. I would have thought something like that was built into XCode 4, but I don't know, as I don't use git. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: nopes..there seems to be a bug in xcode code..it crashes when trying to do a diff